# On what basis should I decide on the optimal number of hash partitions for a given table?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

For example, I would like to create a hash partitioned table like:

```
    CREATE TABLE partition_table (
    some_id INT NOT NULL
) PARTITION BY HASH (some_id);
```

And I start by creating 4 partitions like:

```
CREATE TABLE partition_1 PARTITION OF partition_table FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 4, REMAINDER 0);
CREATE TABLE partition_2 PARTITION OF partition_table FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 4, REMAINDER 1);
CREATE TABLE partition_3 PARTITION OF partition_table FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 4, REMAINDER 2);
CREATE TABLE partition_ PARTITION OF partition_table FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 4, REMAINDER 3);
```

I have read [here](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/how-take-advantage-new-partitioning-features-postgresql-11) that:

> it’s always recommended that the number of tables should be a power of
>   2

On what basis should I decide on the optimal number of partitions for a given table?

Edit:

My objective behind using hash partitioning is to distribute data uniformly. More precisely, I have a table with a hashed-id (that has no logical order), and I would like to distribute data evenly across partitions based on that key.

Comment: Why do you think you need hash partitioning to begin with? What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have updated my post based on your comment, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: "*I would like to distribute data evenly across partitions based on that key*" makes no sense to me. A non-partitioned table with a B-Tree has no "logical order" either. What advantage do you think you get from that? What are the typical queries you are going to run against that table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the table is part of an ETL process. As the table is growing in size, some sorting operations are not fitting in memory and causing problems. My objective is to partition the table, hence allow some calculations to happen in parallel.

Comment: Partitioning won't change anything for a problem when you sort results that are too large to fit into memory.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name to give more context, the calculations (and sorting) happening at each partition are independent & it can be controlled how many parallel tasks to allow running at the same time. What would you recommend to approach these problems?

Comment: If you can control over the results that should be sorted, I don't see how partitioning would improve anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hash partitioning is pretty useless - it is a form of striping using partitioning. The only other advantage I see is that it is easier for autovacuum to maintain several smaller tables than one big table.

In my opinion, hash partitioning only makes sense if each partition is on a different tablespace, and each tablespace uses different storage. Then the number of the partitions should be the number of different independent disks you have available.

I don't see a reason to have a power of two for the number of partitions. The article you reference doesn't give any explanation either, so I'd say forget it.